# postgresql where are temp files stored

Tags: postgresql

Once the work_mem , temp_buffer or maintenence_work_mem is full where does the PostgreSQL writes to the disk, what is the location of temporary files by default

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting location of temp files for Postgresql backend (9.3.10)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167549/setting-location-of-temp-files-for-postgresql-backend-9-3-10)

Answer (score 2):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html)

> Temporary files (for operations such as sorting more data than can fit in memory) are created within `PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp`, or within a `pgsql_tmp` subdirectory of a tablespace directory if a tablespace other than pg_default is specified for them. The name of a temporary file has the form `pgsql_tmpPPP.NNN`, where `PPP` is the PID of the owning backend and `NNN` distinguishes different temporary files of that backend